# Reduce and assign using Stream api for multiple variables

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to do following in lambda but unable to think of way where single stream and reducing(s) can help :(

I have Employee ArrayList where **name** member variable can be duplicate across object in list. I need to create map where key is employee name and value is object where we have **sum** of cost1 and cost2 for that employee.

**Employee class** has -> String name, Integer cost1, Integer cost2

**Output class** has -> Integer cost1, Integer cost2

```
List <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
// data population in inputMap
Map<String, Output> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Employee emp : employeeList)
{
    Output op = outputMap.get(emp.getName());
    if(op == null){
      Output newOp = new Output ();
      newOp.setCost1(emp.getCost1())
      newOp.setCost2(emp.getCost2())
      newOp.put(emp.getName(), newOp);
    }else{
       int cost1 = op.getCost1() + emp.getCost1();
       int cost2 = op.getCost2() + emp.getCost2();
       op.setCost1(cost1);
       op.setCost2(cost2);
       newOp.put(emp.getName(), op);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to do could you spesify more?

Comment: @Eugene : Yes, I can use. But if possible solution using java own  classes will be more helpful in understanding whether it can be done in single stream

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu: For each employee name , sum cost1 and cost2 and put in map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have a structure sort of like this:

```
static class Output {
    private final int cost1;

    private final int cost2;

    public Output(int cost1, int cost2) {
        this.cost1 = cost1;
        this.cost2 = cost2;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "cost1 = " + cost1 + " cost2 = " + cost2;
    }
    // ... getter
}  

static class Employee {
    private final String name;

    private final int cost1;

    private final int cost2;

    public Employee(String name, int cost1, int cost2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost1 = cost1;
        this.cost2 = cost2;
    }
 // ...getters      
}
```

Then the solution would be to first group by `Employee::getName` and reduce to `Output` via `Collectors.reducing`

```
  Map<String, Output> map = Arrays.asList(
                       new Employee("e", 12, 12), 
                       new Employee("f", 13, 13), 
                       new Employee("e", 11, 11))
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                    Collectors.reducing(
                            new Output(0, 0),
                            emp -> new Output(emp.getCost1(), emp.getCost2()),
                            (left, right) -> new Output(left.getCost1() + right.getCost1(), left.getCost2() + right.getCost2()))));
    System.out.println(map); // {e=cost1 = 23 cost2 = 23, f=cost1 = 13 cost2 = 13}
```

Comment: that was awesome. Thanks. Actually, I understood reducing more through your example

Comment: Looks like a task for the `toMap` collector: `Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, emp -> new Output(emp.getCost1(), emp.getCost2()), (left, right) -> new Output(left.getCost1() + right.getCost1(), left.getCost2() + right.getCost2()))`, the same functions, less code and even creating less `Output` instances…

Comment: @Holger I was about to write an answer with `toMap` but then I saw your comment... Well, I'll write it anyway for completeness, with a couple recommendations

Comment: @Holger well.. the OP said `stream and reducing(s) can help`, so I thought "why not"? good point though

Comment: To be fair, I also tend to overlook when `toMap` with a merge function is simpler than `groupingBy`…

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner plz do provide it, it will be a good addition.

Comment: Eugene, added it, thanks. @Holger You could have reduced to the left operand in the merge function, instead of creating a new `Output` instance. This way you create much less `Output` instances. I've done it this way in my answer.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: you are assuming a mutable `Output` class, which this answer doesn’t. Of course, you can’t do that with the `reducing` collector with identity value. If you assume a mutable `Output` class, you can reduce the number of instances even further via `groupingBy` with a downstream collector that creates only a single `Output` instance per group (you are still create one per employee).

Comment: @Holger In the question, OP has provided this code: `Output newOp = new Output (); newOp.setCost1(emp.getCost1())`, so I assumed `Output` was indeed mutable. Using `toMap` is even simpler than `groupingBy` with a downstream collector, IMO.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: not much, compared to your variant: `Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName, Collector.of(Output::new, (o, e) -> { o.setCost1(o.getCost1()+e.getCost1()); o.setCost2(o.getCost2()+e.getCost2()); }, (left, right) -> { left.setCost1(left.getCost1() + right.getCost1()); left.setCost2(left.getCost2() + right.getCost2()); return left; } ))`. As said, that might save much more instances. Otherwise, the `toMap` for immutable `Output` instances is even simpler. The mutable reduction would benefit from an `Output.addToCost1(int)` and `Output.addToCost2(int)` method though…

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you need to get a *reduced* map out of the elements of your stream, you can use the three-argument version of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<String, Output> result = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Employee::getName,
        employee -> new Output(employee.getCost1(), employee.getCost2()),
        (left, right) -> {
            left.setCost1(left.getCost1() + right.getCost1());
            left.setCost2(left.getCost2() + right.getCost2());
            return left;
        }));
```

`Collectors.toMap`, as its name suggests, collects the elements of the stream to a map. Its first argument is a function that converts elements of the stream to keys, the second argument is another function that converts elements of the stream to values, and the third argument is a merge function that is applied to values when there's a collision on the keys.

In this case, I'm using a *mutable* reduction on the left operand of the merge function. This is to avoid creating too many instances of the `Output` class. It is safe to reduce this way because in the value function (the second argument of `Collectors.toMap`) I'm creating a new instance of the `Output` class.

This solution could be greatly improved if you could add the following constructor and method to the `Output` class:

```
// creates an Output instance out of an Employee instance
public Output(Employee employee) {
    this.cost1 = employee.getCost1();
    this.cost2 = employee.getCost2();
}

// merges another Output instance into this Output instance
public Output merge(Output another) {
    this.cost1 += another.cost1;
    this.cost2 += another.cost2;
    return this;
}
```

Now, collecting to the map would be much simpler:

```
Map<String, Output> result = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, Output::new, Output::merge));
```

Comment: I got the point of earlier answer creating more instances everytime. Thanks for providing more efficient solution.